# How to detect overfull and underfull hbox without triggering the warning?

Tags: line-breaking, warnings

I need a LaTeX macro which can be used by this:

```
\IfFull{TEXT}{THEN}{ELSE}
```

It would typeset TEXT in a `\vbox` (which it will discard), and if there was an overfull hbox or an underfull hbox, it would run THEN, otherwise it would run ELSE. It wouldn't report the `Overfull \hbox` or `Underfull \hbox` warnings on the console or in the log file.

Is there such a macro already? If not, how could it be defined?

If this is too complicated, it would be enough to do it for a single paragraph.

Minimal working example, which gives the wrong result, because it always executes `#3`, but in the example it should have executed `#2`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\IfFull#1#2#3{#3}
\begin{document}
\IfFull{\hsize1pt\noindent zzzzz xxxxx}{CORRECT}{BAD}
\end{document}
```

This should create document with the word `CORRECT` in it, because `#1` has an overfull hbox.

Comment: is luatex a possibility? (I'm not sure it's really feasible otherwise)

Comment: With a positive attitude everything is possible :-). Thanks for the `\lastbox` solution. Feel free to give a luatex solution, but most probably we'll go with `\lastbox` to reduce dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like any code using a `\lastbox` loop this will fail badly if there is any unexpected material in the vertical list being measured. specials, inserts, writes, rules, will "hide" any material above the unremovable item.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\IfFull#1{%
  \global\let\@IfFull\@secondoftwo
  \setbox\z@\vbox{%
\hbadness\maxdimen
\hfuzz\maxdimen
#1\par
  \loop
  \unskip\unpenalty\unskip\unpenalty
  \setbox\z@\lastbox
  \ifvoid\z@
  \else
     \setbox0\hbox to \hsize{\unhbox\z@}%
     \ifnum\badness>\tolerance
       \global\let\@IfFull\@firstoftwo
       \typeout{bad: \the\badness}% debug message only
     \fi
  \repeat}%
  \@IfFull}

\begin{document}
\IfFull{\hsize1pt\noindent zzzzz xxxxx}{CORRECT}{BAD}
\end{document}
```